# Vertically Align Text and Image in a Dynamic Height unordered list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I currently have a list of items. Some items are a single line of text and others are 2 lines with a break in between.

I am having difficulty vertically aligning the image to the right of the text. I can align easily when there is only a single line of text, but with multiple lines the image hangs at the top.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=""/>Text Text Text<br/>Second Line of Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="" />Text Text Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="" />Text Text Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is an example of whats happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/SAwFE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use absolute positioning. [Change it to this](http://jsfiddle.net/SAwFE/7/), which has the following revamped code:

```
ul li {
    position: relative; /* added to your existing code */
}

img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /* half height of image */
}
```

To avoid potential overlap (per your comment), then increase the right padding on the `li` by the width of the `img` [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/SAwFE/10/):

```
ul li { 
    padding: 9px 32px 9px 12px; /* modified existing code */
    position: relative; /* added to your existing code */
}
```

Comment: @Michael: add padding on the `li` (see revision of answer) to correct that.

Comment: That was dumb of me to miss that. Thanks. I ended up coming up with the same outcome here using table-cells http://jsfiddle.net/hsXCQ/51/ but I like yours better using the absolute positioning. http://jsfiddle.net/SAwFE/12/